# transform datatable to overlapping multidementional array by group

Tags: r, arrays, data.table, reshape

I am working on a large data.table with 300m rows for different firms, I want to transform the data.table to multidimensional array with overlapping subgroup by GROUP(Firm). Currently, the Following code works for the small toy data, But with my actual data, the calculation nearly never finished so far. I wonder anyone can give me some advice on how to improve it, any help appreciated!
here is my toy data:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(firm = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 9,replace =TRUE),
                 date = c(as.Date("2009-01-01")+0:4, as.Date("2009-01-01")+0:3),
                 x    = c(rep(rep(0:1, each=2), 2),3),
                 y    = rnorm(9),
                 z    = rnorm(9))
```

Here is the working but inefficient code:

```
backward_steps = 2
setkey(dt,firm,date)
dt[, grp := .GRP, by = firm] 
dt[, idx := rowid(dt$firm)] 
n_grp = max(dt$grp)
var_needed <- setdiff(colnames(dt),c("firm","date","grp"))

x_list =list()
for(i in 1:n_grp){ 
  subdt = dt[grp == i,..var_needed]
  setDF(subdt)
  x_lst = lapply(1:(max(subdt$idx) - (backward_steps - 1)), function(x) subdt[subdt$idx %in% (x + 0:(backward_steps - 1)), ])

  for(j in 1:length(x_lst)){
    x_lst[[j]]$idx <- NULL
  }
  if(i == 1){
    x_list = x_lst
  }else{
    x_list = c(x_list, x_lst)
  }
}

X <- abind::abind(x_list, along=0.5)
dim(X) <- c(dim(X), 1)
```

Here is the desired results:

```
dim(X)
[1] 7 2 3 1

X[1,,,]
     [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,]    0 -0.108966  0.2382129
[2,]    0 -0.117242 -1.0488931
```

Thanks!

Comment: just asking, why do you need a multidimensional array? i.e. what are going to do with it after that? or what is the problem that u are trying to solve?

Comment: well, I want to reshape the data as input of CNN model, which require 4D array.

Comment: At which point does it fail? Arrays are likely to eat a lot of memory

Comment: @jangorecki It doesn't fail, It just never finished after 1-2 days.